# .Net BLE Scanner - sniffer and command sender - interface with iHealth BP5

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to communicate with an old iHealth BP5 device via .NET Bluetooth (BLE).
Is there any idea and hint? How legal is that? - I mean to do a SW for PC to interact with such a device

Comment: Actually there is nothing hard. If you do not know how you can use any third-party libraries. 32Feet is free and good enough. Bluetooth Framework is not free but also not bad. Or you can write your own code. In fact for classic devices there is nothing hard. For BLE its a little bit harder but also possible. If you expand your question it is possible to give more detailed answer.

Comment: Is there any BLE PC software which can scan for any BLE device (i.e. iHealth BP7), connect to it and deal with some generic commands? I have some code for Android but I want to create a PC application in C#. THANKS

Comment: I am not sure about existing special software that does exactly you need but for common purpose you can use BLE Explorer from Microsoft. It can scan. connect and read raw data from BLE devices. At least its free. If you need something special you can ping me by Skype or email and I can create such software or explaing how to create it by your self.